# multiple column support for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have noticed that IE 9 and below do not support multiple columns. However, I see this website not loading correct even with the latest Firefox - any idea what in this is preventing multiple columns?

[Here is a CSSDesk](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) of the below:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
.pin {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FEFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.pin img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.pin p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the column-fill: auto; (vendor prefixed too)**

Remove:

```
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
```

HTML (same)

```css
body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/scribble_light.png);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
}
.pin {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FEFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.pin img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.pin p {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  #columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="columns">
    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Nullam eget lectus augue.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8kEc1hS.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1swi3Qy.png" />
      <p>
        Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. Suspendisse id nulla ac urna vestibulum mattis.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
      <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6f3nXse.png" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```